# javascript how to get video's redirected url

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, html5-video

There is a video node looks like this:

```
<video preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%">
    <source src="http://www.example.com/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" label="360p" res="360">
</video>
```

The value of `src` is not real address of that video. Because server would return a 302 response with a `location` header, then redirect to that location. but the location is an ip address.

So how could I get the location with javascript?

Comment: IP address isn't a location?

Comment: @zer00ne ip address is a location. but I could only see it in chrome's network panel. I want to get it by javascript.